# win32com error with cx_freeze and pyttsx

Tags: python, pywin32, cx-freeze

Hi guys have a python software that i want to freeze for distribution. The problem is after freezing it with cx_freeze and i run it, it works fine on my development computer (win 7) but when i sent it to my testing computer (window XP sp3 32bit) it give me this error

```
Traceback(mostresent call last):
File "C:Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line27, in <module?
File "timeTracker.py", line 555, in <module>
File "timeTracker.py", line 381, in __init__
File "timeTracker.py", line 427, in runTimeThread
File "timeTracker.py", line 494, in __init__
File "timeTracker.py", line 118, in __init__
File "C:Python27\lib\site-packages\pyttsx1.1-py2.7.egg\pyttsx\__init__.py", line 39, in init
File "C:Python27\lib\site-packages\pyttsx1.1-py2.7.egg\pyttsx\engine.py", line 45, in __init__
File "C:Python27\lib\site-packages\pyttsx1.1-py2.7.egg\pyttsx\driver.py", line 66, in __init__
File "C:Python27\lib\site-packages\pyttsx1.1-py2.7.egg\pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.py", line 37, in buildDriver
File "C:Python27\lib\site-packages\pyttsx1.1-py2.7.egg\pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.py", line 46, in __init__
File "C:Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 317, in WithEvents
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CLSID'
```

this is my setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
includes =['atexit']
packages = ['pyttsx','win32com.server','win32com.client']
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
setup(
        name = "timeTracker",
        version = "1.0.0",
        description = "Keep track of your time take control of your life",
        options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes, "packages": packages }},
        executables = [Executable("timeTracker.py", base = base)])
```

in the setup.py i tried add 'win32com.gen_py' to the packages list but got the error

```
No module call 'win32com.gen_py'
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems pyttsx has a problem when it comes to window XP. After carefully testing searching i come to the conclusion that  window XP don't have any test to speech engine that is why pyttsx failed

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use pyttsx3. Its way faster, easier to program with, and works with all devices as long as you change the voice engine to fit the computer that you are using like sapi 5 for Windows 10.